# How to get Domain Authority from http://moz.com using GET request?

Tags: html, ruby, rest, seo

I want to get domain authority value from "moz.com" (didn't find other sources).
Sometimes page does not load properly and response from moz.com does not have proper dom elements which I parse. Probably page uses javascript to show values. It also has restriction, can not analyze more than 3 times/day (I need to visit it maximum once a day)

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'nokogiri'

link_url = "http://google.com"
api_url  = "http://moz.com/researchtools/ose/links?site="
response = RestClient.get(api_url + link_url.split("?").first)
value    = Nokogiri::HTML(response).css('.url-metrics-authority span.large').first.text.strip #previously there was Nokogiri::HTML(response).css('.metrics-authority').first.text.strip
pp value
```

From console that works good, but when I run it using ruby script, it fails.
Can I somehow wait for js to execute or are there any other sources to get domain authority?

Comment: can't use their API instead?

Comment: It's paid. It has a lot of requests included, I don't need so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Domain authority for any website/URL by making use of the free URL Metrics API provided by Moz. You will need AccessId and Secret key to consume Mozscape API's. I would suggest you to build a wrapper [API to get Moz Domain Authority](https://www.myjavacode.com/java-api-to-get-domain-authority-and-other-moz-url-metrics/) around the Moz API so that you can consume the wrapper API from the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am Russ Jones and consult for Moz. I also helped architect the latest version of Domain Authority.

The appropriate documentation for [collecting Domain Authority is here](https://moz.com/help/links-api)

Getting an [API Key is free](https://moz.com/help/links-api/getting-started/get-a-key) and allows for 2,500 lookups per month at no faster than 1 every 10 seconds. Paid access starts at $250/mo and includes 120,000 rows per month with significantly fewer restrictions.

Comment: Is it still free? It looks like there is a free *trial* that jumps up to the $250/mo after the trial ends...